# Filesystem metrics from Heapster api is not available

Tags: filesystems, kubernetes, metrics, heapster

I set up `heapster+influxdb+grafana` combination for my `Minikube kubernetes` cluster.
In heapster metrics api documentation they mention about filesystem metrics along with cpu ,memory, network related apis.
 I can get CPU , memory related metrics by using hepster api. 
But I am not able to access filesystem metrics using api. Any help guys?